# Excel Power Query: How to Combine All List Items into Single Row

Tags: powerquery

I have a query to the Cognitive text keyphase API from Microsoft from '16 Excel Power Query - getting keywords from tweets.  Works fine.

However, the JSON doc that's returned per query is converted by Power Query into a list of ~1-5 rows.

In the case of the pic, I want all responses returned to be in one cell/row, regardless of the number of items returned.

[image: List result]

Here is my full M query (you need to put your own key in) if you're interested.

---

```
let
    TweetCognitive = (TweetID as text, TweetText as text) =>
let
    JsonRecords = Text.FromBinary(Json.FromValue([id=TweetID, text=TweetText])),
    JsonRequest = "{""documents"": [" & JsonRecords & "]}",
    JsonContent = Text.ToBinary(JsonRequest, TextEncoding.Ascii),
    Response =
        Web.Contents("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/keyPhrases?",
            [
                Headers = [#"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"="yourkeyhere",
                           #"Content-Type"="application/json", Accept="application/json"],
                       Content=JsonContent 
            ]),
    JsonResponse = Json.Document(Response,1252)
in
    JsonResponse
in
    TweetCognitive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `List.Accumulate` to turn a list of values into a single value.  For example, this would combine the values in the list into a single text value with ". " separating each row's value:

`List.Accumulate(JsonResponse, "", (state, current) => state & current & ". ")`

This would generate `"monday frank love happiness today. nice good kind. tomorrow. "` in your example. If you want to get rid of the trailing space, you can surround the `List.Accumulate` expression with `Text.Trim`.

Comment: Thanks.  I had to add a few lines, but got it to work.  Here's the final add including your line:

 
    JsonDocuments = JsonResponse[documents],
    JsonDocuments1 = JsonDocuments{0},
    keyPhrases = JsonDocuments1[keyPhrases],
    keyPhrasesAccumulated = List.Accumulate(keyPhrases, "", (state, current) => state & current & " ")

in
    keyPhrasesAccumulated

Answer (score 0):

The basic function to concatenate elements in a list is `Text.Combine`.  For instance:

```
Text.Combine(JsonResponse, " ")
```

This avoids the extra delimeter at the end you get with `List.Accumulate`.  Note also `List.Combine` is for creating a longer combined list from shorter lists, and the similar naming there may cause confusion.